# Analyzing memory usage using MAT. Trying to interpret what I see

Tags: android, eclipse, memory

I'm auto-testing my app by loading the same screen over and over. I make heap dumps every 400 screen loads and then try to see whether I have leaks. The screen makes 3 network calls (it loads two XML files and one bitmap file). I noticed this object:

39 instances of "org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute", loaded by "" occupy 6,506,440 (51.72%) bytes.

This is after 800 screen loads. The "funny" thing is that after 400 loads there were 75 instances totaling to about 13MB!

In fact, the strangest thing is, that the heap keeps increasing from 12MB to almost 27MB (I'm not sure if it will go over the 64MB that the device has!). When I stop the automatic loading and repeatedly press "Cause GC" in the Eclipse DDMS Heap section, it keeps drecreasing the "Allocated" memory until I'm almost down to 6MB!? The question I have is, how come the heap size keeps increasing even though it seems I'm not using all that memory. Is it because my memory is defragmented? Should I be able to converse more memory if I don't keep creating new objects but keep an object pool? Should GC not cause an OOM when I reach the critical value of 64MB and should it try to do its best more? I feel kind of uneasy that it would get so close to 64MB. I wish the GC would be more punctual :)

Hope someone can help.

Best,
Joris